# Extract and Separate Numeric

Tags: sql-server, extract, numeric, csv

I have a table below.

```
Client Name
-----------------------
Mukherjee_ 2697231  Gehrmann _ 298053524
Butt  Glen_740708968 Amanda_259055000
Quirk  Michael_ 65941412 and Leanne _817498908
Butt  Glen_740708968 Amanda_259055000 Tristan 3939393939
Kryger  Aaron _ 606506375
Krebs  Paul
Haddrill  Clare  _ 333900499  McRedmond  Patrick _557887778
```

I need to extract the numbers only and the numbers must be separated.

```
Numeric
----------------
2697231  298053524
740708968 259055000
65941412 817498908
740708968 259055000 3939393939
606506375

333900499  557887778
```

I have used the function below, however it concatenates all the numbers together.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_GetNumeric]
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intAlpha INT
    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
    BEGIN
        WHILE @intAlpha > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
            SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
        END
    END
    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking further into this problem, I came up with -->

```
-- partition into non-num and numeric strings, collapse non-num into single space, and copy numeric as is
-- complicating: multiple non-num and multiple numeric strings
-- further, allow for starting with EITHER non-num or numeric
-- further, can have no numeric at all, or can have no non-num at all
```

I put data into table   dbo.separatenumber
And created UDF-->  Revised Jan 15th--del If/Then/Set @next, add Set @LeftMost

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnSeparateNonNumericCharacters]    Script Date: 01/14/2020 21:41:42 ******/
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fnSeparateNonNumericCharacters]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
        DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSeparateNonNumericCharacters]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE Function [dbo].[fnSeparateNonNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) AS
    BEGIN
        Declare @outText as varchar(1000), @LeftMost as char(4), @ndx as int
        Set @outText = ''
        IF PATINDEX('[0-9]', SUBSTRING(@strText,1,1)) = 1   -- is the 1st char numeric?
            Set @LeftMost = 'Nums'
        ELSE
            Set @LeftMost = 'Text'
        ;

    WHILE LEN(@strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF      @LeftMost = 'Text'
            BEGIN
            Set @ndx = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @strText)            -- where is the next Numeric
            If  @ndx = 0 Break                                  -- bail when no more
            Set @strText = SUBSTRING(@strText,  @ndx, LEN(@strText) - @ndx  + 1)    -- bypass Text
            Set @LeftMost = 'Nums'
            END
        ELSE -- @LeftMost = 'Nums'
            BEGIN
            Set @ndx = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText)           -- where is next Text
            If  @ndx = 0 Set @ndx = LEN(@strText) + 1           -- use EOL plus one when no more
            Set @outText += SUBSTRING(@strText, 1, @ndx - 1) + ' '  -- Grab Numbers plus a space
            If  @ndx = LEN(@strText) + 1  Break                 -- bail when no more
            Set @strText = SUBSTRING(@strText,  @ndx, LEN(@strText) - @ndx + 1 )    -- move past this Num
            Set @LeftMost = 'Text'
            END
        ;
    END
    RETURN @outText     -- here it is

END

    GO



select 
    *
    , dbo.fnSeparateNonNumericCharacters(clientname) as Numbers 
from dbo.separatenumber
```

Sample output

```
ClientID    ClientName                      Numbers
11  Mukherjee_ 2697231  Gehrmann _ 298053524            2697231 298053524 
22  Butt  Glen_740708968 Amanda_259055000               740708968 259055000 
33  Quirk  Michael_ 65941412 and Leanne _817498908          65941412 817498908 
44  Butt  Glen_740708968 Amanda_259055000 Tristan           3939393939  740708968 259055000 3939393939 
55  Kryger  Aaron _ 606506375                   606506375
66  Krebs  Paul 
77  Haddrill  Clare  _ 333900499  McRedmond  Patrick _557887778 333900499 557887778
```